# How to replicate UE4 material in Blender?

Tags: materials, unreal-engine

How can I replicate the following material in Blender?

[image: UE4 material]

Comment: Could you point out what the problem exaclty is? Where exactly are you stuck? What render engine are you using?

Comment: It would be also nice if you can provide final look of this material.

Comment: Actually, I couldn't find Lerp, Multiply and right output nodes in Node Editor.

Comment: I was using Blender Render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Cycles Renderer, it's practically node-for-node, with slightly different names.  I assumed "Lightness" was a texture:

[image]

Note that the grayscale/normal map images should be set to "Non-Color Data" so Blender doesn't gamma-correct them.  You might even want that for the colored image in the lower left.

I also didn't know what the empty Lerp would do exactly.  You might need to change the colors on that to black (0,0,0) and pure white (1,1,1) to duplicate an empty lerp node.

If you are trying to use Blender Render, then I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: However, materials look different in Blender and in UE (no smooth and strange roughness?)
Blender: https://pasteboard.co/HKRLmrH.png
UE: https://pasteboard.co/HKRLDss.png
.blend file: https://dropmefiles.com/ijiZa

Comment: The clothes' gloss depends on Clearcoat, but I don't understand why Sheen doesn't work.

Comment: For one thing, the lighting you have in that UE view is WAY different than the skylight you put in Blender, which is one reason it looks different.  Also a couple of things: you didn't change the colors of that Mix (lerp) node at the bottom...I think in UE it would be black/white, not gray/gray.  Regarding Sheen, that is meant for things like velvet or cloth, so it adds a little reflection around the edges.  It's not meant for a piece of hard armor like this.